# Property cupertinoCalculateChunkIDBasedOnTimecode in Wowza

Tags: wowza, http-live-streaming

I am using Wowza Engine 4.5.0 and I am trying to change the chunk ID numbering based on incoming packet time, instead of the default sequential number that cause problems when restarting the encoder.

From something like this

```
   ...media_w112312312_b1024000_7.ts
   ...media_w112312312_b1024000_8.ts
```

to a timestamp notation where the chunks continue even after a restart

I read about the property cupertinoCalculateChunkIDBasedOnTimecode, I follow the instructions in this guide to configure it:

https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-configure-apple-hls-packetization-cupertinostreaming#livepropref

but it does not work or I am doing something wrong. Has anyone used the property 
 cupertinoCalculateChunkIDBasedOnTimecode successfully?

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have used 'cupertinoCalculateChunkIDBasedOnTimecode' property and even if I  restart my encoder, players are able to pick up the stream and play successfully.

The below page will help you in using it properly
http://thewowza.guru/how-to-set-stream-timecodes-to-absolute-time/